# Else-if element ID doesn't exist

Tags: javascript

I have a collection of clickable items. Each page generates new items based on what a user has chosen. I want to be able to run some code based on if a specific ID exists and if it doesn't exist I don't want it to run. This is what I have tried so far:

```
function pageLoad() {
    var ums = document.getElementById('DIVID').innerHTML;
    if(ums == "IN (INCHES)") {
        allFunctionsInvoked();
        }   
}
```

I'm getting this error message when the element doesn't exist:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
```

causing my program to freeze up. I've tried adding an else if statement to check if the ID is null, but still can't get a way to resolve it.

Comment: that means `getElementById` is returning null, meaning it isnt finding an element with an id attribute of `DIVID`

Comment: I hope this fiddle will help: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/rac8hbxe/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.getElementById()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) will return `null` if an element with the specified ID is not in the document.

Therefore you can check if the element is not `null` before retrieving the `innerHTML` property:

```
function pageLoad() {
    var element = document.getElementById('DIVID');

    if (element !== null && element.innerHTML == "IN (INCHES)") {
        allFunctionsInvoked();
    }   
}
```

As a side note, if you're just checking for a string of text, you could access the [`textContent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of the `innerHTML` property:

```
function pageLoad() {
    var element = document.getElementById('DIVID');

    if (element !== null && element.textContent === "IN (INCHES)") {
        allFunctionsInvoked();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Brilliant mate! This really saved me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this value for being `null`:

```
function pageLoad() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('DIVID');

    if (elem === null) {
        console.log("No DIVID element.");
        return;
    }

    if (elem.innerHTML == "IN (INCHES)") {
        allFunctionsInvoked();
    }   
}
```

It is also possible to simply use `!elem` since `null` is **falsy**:

```
function pageLoad() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('DIVID');

    if (!elem) {
        console.log("No DIVID element.");
        return;
    }

    if (elem.innerHTML == "IN (INCHES)") {
        allFunctionsInvoked();
    }   
}
```

Comment: `elem` will be `null` not `undefined`

Comment: @RayonDabre Thank you. Please, check the updated answer!